# Simulate "visit" for javascript analytics tracker

Tags: javascript, php, matomo

I am using Piwik/Matomo's tracker to provide my users with custom JS trackers, and provide a curated dashboard of analytics that are tailor made for them. One problem I am facing consistently is verifying if the tracker is installed and working correctly.

I have tried using `file_get_contents` and/or `cURL` to fetch the page and check if the tracker exists, but this doesn't always work. So I am trying to instead simulate a visit, and see if the tracker sends me any data when it happens.

Since fget/curl do not trigger javascript, is there an alternative (and lightweight) method to fire the page's javascript and trigger a visit for testing?

**Update :** I implemented this by using PhantomJS as suggested, with the overall function being something like this. Haven't yet tested this extensively for all my users, is there a more elegant solution? -

```
checktracker
{
    if (data exists & data > 0)
    {
        return true
    }
    else if (data exists & data = 0)
    {
        simulate visit with phantomJS //Relevant to question
        check again
        if ( still 0 )
        {
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            return true
        }
    }
    else
    {
        invalid site id
    }
}
```

Comment: The JS trackers are just making requests to the tracking API.
https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/tracking-api
You can use whatever you want to access this HTTP API.

Comment: @LukasWinkler That would only confirm that the server is receiving the tracker's inputs, but how would it confirm that the actual JS tracker is present and functional?

Comment: You could fetch the page with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) - it will load it like your browser and therefore execute JS and trigger your tracking request

Answer (score 0):

So you want to automatically check if a specific website has integrated Matomo correctly? I recently wanted to do the same to create a browser extention to quickly debug common errors.

One way would be checking the DOM. The Matomo Tracking Code adds a `<script>`-Tag to the website, so you can check the existence of it via JavaScript:

```
function getDomElements() {
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (allElements[i].hasAttribute("src") && allElements[i].getAttribute("src").endsWith("piwik.js")) { // TODO: support renamed piwik.js
            return allElements[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But if you also have access to the JS console, the probably better solution would be checking if the tracking code has initialized correctly:

If something like this outputs your Matomo URL, chances are high that the tracking code is embedded correctly.

```
var tracker == window.Piwik.getAsyncTracker()
console.log(tracker.getPiwikUrl())
```

Of course it can still fail (e.g. if the server returns 403 on the `piwik.php` request, but  if you control the server, this shouldn't happen)

To run the check automatically, you could look into Headless Chrome or Firefox.